# how to remove the first '|' for selected sentences in notepad

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I would to remove the first | which appear in some sentences. For example:

```
aaa | bbb | ccc 
|dd | eee | ff
gg | hh | jj
|zz | xx | vv
```

I would to remove only the '|' in notepad which appear at the beginning of some rows.

I expect the following output:

```
aaa | bbb | ccc 
dd | eee | ff
gg | hh | jj
zz | xx | vv
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\|`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>